# Why does my Honda Activa 4G handle vibrate a lot at low speed?

Tags: vibration, scooter, activa, handlebars

I bought an Activa 4G in January 2018, the vibrations started after 120kms.
My 1st service was at 350kms(I did not use much). after the service the vibrations was not there. but after 650kms the vibrations again started. now I have completed 1000kms. Do I need to wait until my next service or any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you report the vibrations when you took it for the first service? When is your next service? If it is soon then report it then, if not take it in to get it looked at.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather general question. Without knowing anything about your riding style or habits, nor the conditions you ride in, or how you maintain your scooter, I am going to give you a couple things I think may be causing vibration in the handlebars.

1. Wheel balancing and alignment caused by hitting bumps/potholes
2. Poor running engine
3. Bad fuel causing #2

If the vibration is enough to concern you, or effect your ability to safely ride, then do not wait to have it serviced.